# Cancellation in Numerical Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, computer-arithmetic

How do you find the values of $x$ for which for example, $f(x) = 1-\cos(x)$ cannot be computed accurately? From different websites I see that this happens for large $x$-values, but I am not sure how to determine that.

Comment: This is not a typical example because $\cos$ is a periodical function ($\cos(x+k 2 \pi)=\cos(x)$) therefore large values of $x$ can always be brought back to small values of $x$...

Comment: There was a tangentially related (and interesting in it own right) unpublished 1983 note by W. Kahan called Minimizing  q * m - n". The point being range reduction by subtracting multiples of $\pi$. However, I cannot find the note, I may have recycled it :-(.

Answer (score 0):

For numerical computation of $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, it is usually best to normalize the argument $x$ to be within the range $[-\pi, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$, depending on the library's implementation of those trigonometric functions.

In numerical computation, subtraction operations destroy precision when the operands are very close in value, i.e. when $\cos(x)$ is near $1$ in your example.

So when the argument $x$, when normalized, is close to $0$ or $2\pi$, it may be better to compute $1-\cos(x)$ as $2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$, or some other equivalent form, instead.  It really depends on whether or not the loss of precision really matters for your problem.

Comment: Would you please clarify what do you mean by normalizing the argument?

Comment: $\cos(x) = \cos(x +2\pi k)$, so just add or subtract multiples of $2\pi$ until the argument is in the range $[-\pi, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$.  Mathematically they are the same, but numerically, it can matter to the library implementation of $\cos(x)$ with respect to accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Is it then true to say that to find such x-values for which a function cannot be accurately computed we need to find the x-values for rich the operands are very close in value (if we subtract them)?

Comment: Preserving accuracy and precision in numerical computation with finite precision is a very broad topic.  There are some simple rules of thumb: "avoid subtraction of numbers of similar magnitude", "don't divide by small numbers", "don't directly invert a matrix", etc. but these need rigorous definitions of of "close" and "small" to be useful.  Such definitions are based on machine epsilon and your allowed error tolerance.   Anyway, there are whole textbooks written on the subject of numerical computation, usually at the 1st year undergraduate level.

Answer (score 0):

Even for small $x$ you have a problem computing $1-\cos x$.  The Taylor series shows that for small $x$ we have $\cos x \approx 1-\frac {x^2}2$  If your float has $53$ bits of precision like a typical $64$ bit number, you lose the difference from $1$ when $x \lt 2^{-26}$  The problem was much worse when floats were only $32$ bits with $24$ bits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $f(x)=1-\cos x$ suggests the algorithm
$$
z_1 = \cos x, \qquad z_2 = 1-z_1
$$

Now it is just a matter of computing the relative error of the outcome (i'm assuming $\cos x\ne0$, but this is not a problematic case):

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{z_1} =& \frac{x (- \sin x)}{\cos x} \varepsilon_x + \varepsilon_{1}\\
\varepsilon_{z_2} = & z_1 \frac{-1}{1-z_1} \varepsilon_{z_1} + \varepsilon_2=-\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos x}\left( \frac{x (- \sin x)}{\cos x} \varepsilon_x + \varepsilon_{1}\right) + \varepsilon_{2}\\
= & \frac{x \sin x}{\cos x - 1} \varepsilon_x + \frac{\cos x}{\cos x - 1} \varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2
\end{align*}

This last expression expresses the relative error in the output in terms of the reltive error in the input ($\varepsilon_x$) adn the roundoff errors in the different steps of the algorithm. The algorithm becomes unstable when one or more coefficients are unbounded, which is the case of $\frac{\cos x}{\cos x -1}$. This is just a quantification of an obvious fact: if $\cos x$ is small (but not zero) and it is computed as zero the relative error computing $1-\cos x$ becomes infinite.